# Flutter Dropdown to be centered in the middle of screen and only show a few items?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Currently I'm trying to create a dropdown that is at the right side of the screen and when you click on it to select a weight, it will pop up in the middle of the screen and only show a few of the weights and the rest of it is surrounded with padding, just like this picture: ([Just like this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkrA1.jpg))

[This is what mine looks like at the minute with the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZroY.png)

Thank you so much!

```
class Weight {
int amount;

Weight(this.amount);

static List<Weight> getWeight() {
return <Weight>[
  Weight(66),
  Weight(67),
  Weight(68),
  Weight(69),
  Weight(70),
  Weight(71),
  Weight(72),
  Weight(73),
  Weight(74),
  Weight(75),
  Weight(76),
];
}

static List<DropdownMenuItem<Weight>> buildDropdownMenuItemsWeight(
  List weightAmount) {
List<DropdownMenuItem<Weight>> items = List();


for (Weight weight in weightAmount) {
  items.add(DropdownMenuItem(
    value: weight,
    child: Text('${weight.amount} Lbs'),
  ));
}
return items;
}


 // Bottom that I'm using on the other page, to reference the above class to display the items in dropdown.
 DropdownButton(
      value: _selectedWeightSystem,
      items: _dropdownMenuItems,
      onChanged: onChangeDropdownItemWeightSystem,
 ),
```

Answer (score 0):

It have had the package to solve your problem already. Use this [numberpicker](https://pub.dev/packages/numberpicker). It also support the UI as the example you give

Comment: Thank you. Is there one of these that I can use that could be used for strings? and not just integers/decimals?

Comment: If you want to implement to your code, i see that the weight is all number, so just pick number and convert it to string. Anyway, it still have this package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_picker

Comment: Hi Hoangquyy, thank you for your help! I am currently doing this. https://imgur.com/B1Mx20D  and I looked at that Flutter_Picker package and it looks confusing. I'm just trying to do the same thing you suggested with the NumberPicker, I love the way that looks. Any suggestions? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad to help you @Jacob , I don't know how your app work, if you want to select your Weight instance, just add an init function for Weight then put the number you get from number picker as a parameter to create Weight object, then you can update the Weight with the number you select.